# How to check if file is selected

Tags: php

I have file `$fileImage = $_FILES['fileCatImg'];`, everything works when I try to upload it, but how do I check if file is selected first? `if (isset($fileImage))` and `if (empty($fileImage))` are not working. One of them always returns true value, but other always returns false value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check file size:

```
if($_FILES['fileCatImg']['size'] > 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

No file was uploaded when `$_FILES['fileCatImg']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`, but that is only useful to determine an appropriate error message. See [Error Messages Explained](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) for other values that `$_FILES['fileCatImg']['error']` might assume when something goes wrong during file uploads.